# OneDrive REST API - Upload - Files > 4GB

Tags: rest, onedrive

Uploading files greater than 4GB using the OneDrive REST API fails.

Sample request:

```
PUT https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.<removed>/files/test.vmdk HTTP/1.1
<removed>
Content-Length: 10000000000
Host: apis.live.net
```

Since it is now possible to upload files up to 10Gb using the OneDrive website and the Desktop client it would be great if this is also possible with the REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're getting this published on the documentation site in the next content refresh, but I wrote up a quick gist on how to upload files larger than the REST APIs 100MB limit.

https://gist.github.com/rgregg/37ba8929768a62131e85

For large files, the best results will be achieved by splitting the file into multiple fragments and uploading those fragments. That way if a connection is dropped after you uploaded 90% of the files (in smaller fragments) you can recover the upload with the last fragment instead of starting all over again.